# why disproportionation of free radicals does not happen in kolbe's electrolysis if we use secondary or tertiary carboxylic salt as substrate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrolysis

In notes given by chemistry teacher, for secondary carboxylic salts the final products are alkane and ester.

[image]

but i guess, as the reaction intermediates involve secondary/tertiary free radicals, some radicals should also go under disproportionation reaction and produce alkene.

[image]

why this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the free-radical-scavenging activity of the secondary/tertiary  carboxylic salts?

Hence, radicals that could possibly undergo disproportionation reactions resulting in alkene are removed.

As a possible example, see ['Evaluation of the Free-Radical-Scavenging Activity of Diclofenac Acid on the Free-Radical-Induced Haemolysis of Human Erythrocytes'](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16640831/).